# Date with an option for end date being either a date or "ongoing"

Tags: entities

I have a content type that contains relevant information of a project. It should hold the projects start date and the end date OR the status "ongoing". How do I make this happen? With the date field type I can only specify the starting and ending dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an additional field named *Project status* with 2 options *Done* and *ongoing*. Then using the [Conditional fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module, show the date field when *Done* is selected and hide it when *ongoing* is selected.

Comment: Thank you, that's great! Just too bad that the version for drupal 7 is still in dev phase so use on production site is discouraged. I'll probably try to sort this out in similar fashion but with jQuery :D